# Bash - substring extraction

Tags: bash, awk, cygwin, substring

I have a variable `"$var"` of type: `"YYYYMMDD_charcharchar...charchar.ext"`
After the first "_" there can be other one (1 or more) or none.

I have to truncate the first part `"YYYYMMDD_"` and leave in a `$new_var` `"charcharchar...charchar.ext"`.

I can't use "bash expansions" like
`${string:position}`
because I'm into emulated environment (Cygwin)

thanks.

Comment: AFAIK Bash is also available under Cygwin. Have you tried `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` as shebang?

Comment: bash expansions work just fine in cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the question with awk, so here is an example with awk:

```
$ var="YYYYMMDD_foo_bar_blah"
$ newV=$(awk 'sub(/^[^_]*_/,"")' <<<$var) 
$ echo $newV
foo_bar_blah
```

Comment: `<<<` is unlikely to work if `${string:position}` is unavailable.

Comment: @chepner then `newV=$(echo "$var" | awk..)`

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done using `cut`:

```
var="YYYYMMDD_charcharchar...charchar.ext"

new_var=$(echo "$var" | cut -d_ -f2-)
```

Check output:

```
echo "$new_var"

charcharchar...charchar.ext
```

Comment: `<<<` is unlikely to work if `${string:position}` is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use parameter expansion:

```
new_var=${var#*_}
```

The `#` operator removes from the expansion the shortest prefix matching `*_` (which would be any characters up to and including the first `_`).